# Electron: where do the main process stacktraces go?

Tags: electron, electron-forge

When running in dev mode, errors stack traces show up in the terminal. When running the fully packaged app (packaged with electron-forge) from the terminal, there is no standard output (both on Mac and Windows). Where can I find the stack traces of the errors that have been thrown, and the whole main process logs?

Note that I tried to use `--enable-logging --log-file=...` and the stack traces are not in there.